# Error when opening Web Analytics reports

Tags: sharepoint-server, searchserviceapplication

I'm not able to open any of the built-in Web Analytics reports in the Search Server 2010 Express edition. In the log file there's an error

> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Resources.MossChart.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "App_GlobalResources.jbeami-m" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

This [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4a89e23c-a1c1-4b8a-99e9-4e1a36b8ecf8/web-analytics-errors?forum=sharepointadminprevious) gives a solution, but I'm not able to find any of these 2 files: 'mosschart.resx' and 'mosschart.en-US.resx'.

Where can I get these resource files?

Comment: Resource files are located in the hive (14 if you're using SP 2010) at: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Resources

Comment: I checked that location and I didn't find the files I'm looking for.